# Cloudflare changes content-encoding from gzip to brotli

Tags: heroku, compression, gzip, cloudflare, brotli

We serve out our React Application from a NodeJS Express server using GZIP compression.

```
// app.js
app.get('*.js', (req, res, next) => {
  req.url = req.url + '.gz'; // eslint-disable-line
  res.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
  next();
});

// webpack config
new CompressionPlugin({
  algorithm: 'gzip',
  test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
  threshold: 10240,
  minRatio: 0.8,
}),
```

We use Heroku for our deployments and Cloudfare as our Reverse Proxy. When I check the Chrome DevTools network tab, I see that the requests are coming through [Brotli compressed](https://github.com/google/brotli)

```
access-control-allow-credentials: ---
access-control-allow-headers: ---
access-control-allow-methods: ---
access-control-allow-origin: ---
access-control-expose-headers: ---
access-control-max-age: ---
cf-ray: ---
content-encoding: br
content-type: text/plain
date: Wed, 27 Feb 2019 22:46:29 GMT
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
server: cloudflare
status: 200
via: 1.1 vegur
```

Does anybody know if this is some sort of progressive enhancement from Cloudflare's side that updates the compression to `br` from `gzip` for supported clients? I see that we can enable Brotli via the [Cloudflare dashboard](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168396-What-will-Cloudflare-compress-) but we have not enabled this. Also I understand that if resources are already gzip compressed, Cloudflare would respect that. Any ideas on why the compression is `br` instead of `gzip`?